# Activity crashed after starting new Fragment

Tags: android

I try to make my `StartActivity` class can dynamically change from one `Fragment` to another, such as first it will open up `LoginFragment`. If user does not have any account they could register new account. Login and register would be two different fragments in a single activity.

Here's the `StartAcitivity.class`

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.flDetailContainer, new LoginFragment(), "LOGIN")
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

My `LoginFragment.class`

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, parent, false);
    }
}
```

And the `activity_start.xml` layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/flDetailContainer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

</FrameLayout>
```

My `fragment_login.xml` layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the error I got.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.asus.carclubapps, PID: 2748
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asus.carclubapps/com.example.asus.carclubapps.StartActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006f (com.example.asus.carclubapps:id/activity_start) for fragment RegistrationFragment{85ef24b #0 id=0x7f0c006f}
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006f (com.example.asus.carclubapps:id/activity_start) for fragment RegistrationFragment{85ef24b #0 id=0x7f0c006f}
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1098)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I do have RegistrationFragment and fragment_registration, but the thing is on my StartActivity I only call for LoginFragment not RegistrationFragment yet. Am I missing something here?

---

RegistrationFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Asus on 11/27/2016.
 */

public class RegistrationFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration, parent, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_registration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_registration"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project and then run again.Do you have any other fragment name RegistrationFragment

Comment: Please add your `RegistrationFragment` in your question.

Comment: From Logs its clear in your RegistrationFragment you are trying to access some view which actually not exist in your attached layout file of fragment.

So confirm in your RegistrationFragment that you attached correct view. Because generally this error(View not found) comes when you trying to use view which actually not exist with current attached view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logcat clearly indicates that the problem is in your `RegistrationFragment` in the `activity_start.xml` layout.

```
No view found for id 0x7f0c006f (com.example.asus.carclubapps:id/activity_start) for fragment RegistrationFragment{85ef24b #0 id=0x7f0c006f}
```

It also says you're referring to an invalid view which doesn't really exists in your `activity_start.xml` layout.

Here's your `activity_start.xml` layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/flDetailContainer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

</FrameLayout>
```

I see one and only `FrameLayout` with id `flDetailContainer` which you might not want to get from your `RegisterFragment`. I think you're getting wrong view inside your `RegisterFragment` where you're getting the view from layout using `LayoutInflater`.

I guess, there's a layout called `fragment_register.xml`. You need to get the view from that layout in your `RegisterFragment`.

In that case your `onCreateView` function of the `RegisterFragment` may look like

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have registration fragment and its own layout. But the thing is, on my StartActivity class I only call  for LoginFragment. Not RegistrationFragment. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Reaz Good explanation, UpVote from my side :)

Comment: Thanks @rahulkapoor. Good to see your answer was helpful and marked as accepted. Looks like it actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From Logs its clear in your *RegistrationFragment* you are trying to access some view which actually not exist in your attached layout file of fragment.

So confirm in your *RegistrationFragment* that you attached correct view. Because generally this **error**(View not found) comes when you trying to use view which actually not exist with current attached view.

If still not works then try to invalidate cache and restart you Android Studio.

Comment: You may be referring to the same thing as @ReazMurshed, but his answer is an actual answer. Your answer is barely just a comment. So you should post it as a comment on the question.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the error is coming from another Activity, Mainly the Registerfragment. The view is incorrect.

```
 Unable to start activity --> No view found for fragment RegistrationFragment
```

If you fix the view and the problem is persistant, kindly update us and we will work it out promptly.

Comment: @IhsanRamli Try to clean your project, invalidate cache and restart your studio